# Text moves down when i added logo in header slide

Tags: beamer, texlive

I have a problem with that, when added to the header slide logo, text (learn, describe, implement, compare as you can see on the pictures) moves little bit down and I do not know why. Have you a solution? Thanks

Here is the code with logo in header:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[anchor=north east,yshift=2pt,xshift=2pt] at (current page.north east) {\includegraphics[height=0.8cm]{vutlogo}};
\end{tikzpicture}}}

\frame{ 
   \frametitle{Work targets}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Learn\,\dots
            \item Describe\,\dots
            \item Implement\,\dots
            \item Compare\,\dots
        \end{itemize}
}
\end{document}
```

[image: Slide with logo in the header]

Here is the code without logo in header:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\frame{ 
   \frametitle{Work targets}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Learn\,\dots
            \item Describe\,\dots
            \item Implement\,\dots
            \item Compare\,\dots
        \end{itemize}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the height/depth of the logo is causing the following material to be moved down.  if there is always a title to the left that will provide the desired depth, it would suffice to set the logo in such a way that it appears to have zero heght + depth, while not affecting its position on the page.  unfortunately, i'm not familiar enough with `tikz` to provide code.

Comment: I tried to adjust the height = 0.8 cm 0 cm and then omit the parameter completely height, but the text is always shifted down.

Comment: You can put a `\vspace{-\baselineskip}` or other value before  `\begin{tikzpicture}...` and shift the text up as needed.

Comment: Yea command \vspace{-\baselineskip} solved my problem. And you know how to apply for every frame (slide) ?

Comment: Simply put the `\vspace{-\baselineskip}` after `\end{tikzpicture}`. Btw: in your MWE there seems to be a superfluous `}` at this location.

Comment: @alwaysask Do you want to convert your comment into an answer? It sounds, as if it solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a `\vspace{-\baselineskip}` or other value before `\begin{tikzpicture}` and shift the text up as needed.